# How to see if the characters of one string appear in order in a second string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given two strings, "word" and "key", how can I write a method `sequence_search(word, key)` that returns `true` (else `false`) if the characters in "key" appear in the same order (but not necessarily contiguous) in "word"?

Suppose, for example, `key = 'cat'`. The method should return `true` if "word" equals `"arcata"`, `"c1a2t3"` or `"coat"`, but return `false` if "word" equals `"cta"`.

Here is my attempt to answer the question:

```
def sequence_search(word, key)
    arr = []
    i = 0
    while i < word.length
     word[i].include?(key)
    arr >> word[i]
      end
      i+= 1
    end
      if arr.join == key  # line raising exception
        return true
      else false
      end
    end
```

When I run my code I get the exception:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `arr' for main:Object)
```

in the line indicated. Why? And is there a better way to write the method?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I recommend writing our your solution as pseudocode first. In this case, you are checking the string for the _first character in the key_, then you search the remaining part of the word for the _next character in the key_, and so on

Comment: I trust you don't mind my edit. You are of course free to make any further changes or roll-back to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the problem with your code it helpful to first format it properly.

```
def sequence_search(word, key)
  arr = []
  i = 0
  while i < word.length
    word[i].include?(key)
    arr >> word[i]
  end
  i += 1
end

if arr.join == key  # line raising exception
  return true
else
  false
end

end
```

As you see, the method does not end where you thought it did and there is an extra `end`. Some of the problems are as follows:

- the `while` loop will never end because `i` is not incremented within the loop;
- `arr >> word[i]` should be `arr << word[i]`
- `word[i].include?(key)` has no effect, as it's return value is not used (you may want `arr << word[i] if word[i].include?(key)`);
- the logic is wrong: after correcting the code if `word = "acat"` (which contains `"cat"`) you are trying to construct the array `arr #=> ["a", "c", "a", "t"]`, which you will join (to produce `"acat"`) and compare with `"cat"` (`if arr.join == key`), which would (erroneously) fail.

Here are two ways you could write the method.

**Use `String#index` to step through `word` looking for each character of `key`**

```
def sequence_search(word, key)
  i = -1
  key.each_char.all? { |c| i = word.index(c,i+1) }
 end
```

```
sequence_search("arcata", "cat") #=> true
sequence_search("c1a2t3", "cat") #=> true
sequence_search("cta", "cat")    #=> false
sequence_search("coat", "cat")   #=> true
```

See [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-index), with particular attention to the optional second argument, the offset into the string at which the search is to begin.

**Use a regular expression**

```
def sequence_search(word, key)
  word.match?(/#{key.chars.join(".*")}/)
end
```

```
sequence_search("arcata", "cat") #=> true
sequence_search("c1a2t3", "cat") #=> true
sequence_search("cta", "cat")    #=> false
sequence_search("coat", "cat")   #=> true
```

When `key = "cat"`,

```
/#{key.chars.join(".*")}/
  #=> /c.*a.*t/
```

The regular expression reads, "match a 'c' followed by zero or more characters followed by 'a' followed by zero or more characters followed by 't'.

Answer (score 1):

Delete every char which is not in the key, and check if the key is included in the remainder:

```
def sequence_search(str, key)
  str.delete("^#{key}").include?(key) # ^ means "everything but"
end
```

Comment: Niiiice! It's kind of going at it backwards, but using `delete` and `include` lets C do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what solution are you looking for, but this a quick solution for me:

```rb
def sequence_search(word, key)
  arr = key.split('')
  arr.each do |c|
    return false if word.index(c) == nil
    word.slice!(0, word.index(c) + 1)
    return true if arr.last == c
  end
end


sequence_search('cat', 'cat') #=> true
sequence_search('cdadsas', 'cat') #=> false
sequence_search('gdfgddfgcgddadsast', 'cat') #=> true
sequence_search('gdfgddfgcgddadsast', 'cat4') #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful information:

```
require 'benchmark'

N = 100_000

puts 'Ruby %s' % RUBY_VERSION

def cary1(word, key)
  i = -1
  key.each_char.all? { |c| i = word.index(c,i+1) }
end

def cary2(word, key)
  word.match?(/#{key.chars.join(".*")}/)
end

def steenslag(str, key)
  str.delete("^#{key}").include?(key) # ^ means "everything but"
end

def estebes(word, key)
  arr = key.split('')
  arr.each do |c|
    return false if word.index(c) == nil
    word.slice!(0, word.index(c) + 1)
    return true if arr.last == c
  end
end

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('cary1')     { N.times { cary1("arcata", "cat") } }
  x.report('cary2')     { N.times { cary2("arcata", "cat") } }
  x.report('steenslag') { N.times { steenslag("arcata", "cat") } }
  x.report('estebes')   { N.times { estebes("arcata", "cat") } }
end
```

```
# >> Ruby 2.7.1
# >> Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
# >> cary1       0.128231   0.000218   0.128449 (  0.128572)
# >> cary2       0.461305   0.000509   0.461814 (  0.462048)
# >> steenslag   0.055794   0.000026   0.055820 (  0.055847)
# >> estebes     0.263030   0.000185   0.263215 (  0.263399)
# >> ------------------------------------ total: 0.909298sec
# >> 
# >>                 user     system      total        real
# >> cary1       0.131944   0.000141   0.132085 (  0.132227)
# >> cary2       0.453452   0.000626   0.454078 (  0.454374)
# >> steenslag   0.055342   0.000026   0.055368 (  0.055394)
# >> estebes     0.255280   0.000156   0.255436 (  0.255607)
```

Using [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity):

```
require 'fruity'

puts 'Ruby %s' % RUBY_VERSION

def cary1(word, key)
  i = -1
  key.each_char.all? { |c| i = word.index(c,i+1) }
end

def cary2(word, key)
  word.match?(/#{key.chars.join(".*")}/)
end

def steenslag(str, key)
  str.delete("^#{key}").include?(key) # ^ means "everything but"
end

def estebes(word, key)
  arr = key.split('')
  arr.each do |c|
    return false if word.index(c) == nil
    word.slice!(0, word.index(c) + 1)
    return true if arr.last == c
  end
end

compare do
  _cary1     { cary1("arcata", "cat") } 
  _cary2     { cary2("arcata", "cat") } 
  _steenslag { steenslag("arcata", "cat") } 
  _estebes   { estebes("arcata", "cat") } 
end
```

```
# >> Ruby 2.7.1
# >> Running each test 8192 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> _steenslag is faster than _cary1 by 2x ± 0.1
# >> _cary1 is faster than _estebes by 2x ± 0.1
# >> _estebes is faster than _cary2 by 2x ± 0.1
```